# What is the corresponding instanceof target for text nodes?

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out what the corresponding `instanceof` test would be appropriate for text nodes. In the node list example below there's tables and breaks that I can skip over with

```
child = paymentInfo[i];
if (child instanceof HTMLBRElement || child instanceof HTMLTableElement) {
    continue;
}
```

Is there not an analogous test for evaluating the text nodes? Seems experimenting on HTMLTextAreaElement isn't the right hit.

[image: NodeList with varied node types, including text elements]

There's a workaround by checking the nodeName I figured out, but it would be nice to keep the code in harmony with other conditionals.

```
paymentInfo[0].nodeName == "#text"
true
```

Comment: An answer has already been posted ; I can add that with dev tools (F12), and selecting any text node, by looking in the properties tab, you can see that the selected node as `Text` as value for the `__proto__` property, which tell us it "inherits" from this kind of Node, thus you can use `instanceof Text`.

Comment: Great tip @Pierre! I made the mistake of assuming all types had the `HTMLXXXElement` form, but that's simply false. When I went drilling around my tab completion off HTML nothing reasonable landed on Text besides TextArea. Good to know.

Answer (score 5):

The associated constructor is `Text` (`window.Text`), so you can use `instanceof Text`:

```js
const foo = document.querySelector('#foo');
const textNode = foo.childNodes[0];
console.log(textNode instanceof Text);
```

```html
<div id="foo">someText</div>
```

If you want have a reference to a parent element and want to look at child *elements*, while skipping over child *text nodes*, you can use `.children` to get an HTMLCollection of children elements (instead of `.childNodes`, which gives you a NodeList of both children text nodes and children elements):

```js
const foo = document.querySelector('#foo');
const children = foo.children;
console.log(children.length);
console.log(children[0]);
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  someText
  <div id="someChild">someChild</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but `querySelector()` is supposed to deal with a language, while `getElementById()` exactly knows what argument it gets. Thus I would say `querySelector()` is reliably slower, even if it has some direct code paths for simple queries (like there is one for simple strings between backticks in V8). Btw, `foo` automatically becomes a variable in many environments anyway.

Comment: At least on modern browsers, a `querySelector` with a `#` is about as fast as `getElementById`. It's just my personal preference, but I always use `querySelector` by default because performance isn't an issue and because it's far more flexible. Yeah, IDs automatically get assigned to the window, but relying on that is bad practice, so I don't want to use it in answers that people may copy code from